# what's the best way to reference parent/containing nodejs module?

Tags: node.js

```
myModule
  |__index.js
  |__foo.js
  |__bar.js
```

Inside of foo.js I want to reference myModule (parent). What's the best way of doing that?

I am currently debating between one of the following:

```
var parent = module.parent.exports
var parent = require('./');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use __dirname to reference the parent module.

Comment: That essentially does the same as "./". Is there a built-in nodejs way of referencing containing module?